# c:forEach issue when part of javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I have a java script function where if you hit the add button it will add a new row to the table so you can fill it out and then save it.  It doesn't seem to like when I put the c:forEach in it as it is giving me quote symbol expected error on the var=\"budget\"  The function is below.  Any thoughts on what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

```
<script language="javascript">
function Add(){
$("#budgetTbl tbody").append(
    "<tr>"+
    "<td>"+     
        "<select>"+
            "<option selected=\"selected\" value=\"None Selected\">None Selected</option>"+
                           "<c:forEach var=\"budget\" items=\"${budgetName}\">"+
                "<option>${budget.budgetName}</option>"+
            "</c:forEach>"+
            "</select>"+
    "</td>"+
    "<td><input placeholder=\"Projected\" type='text' id==\"amount\" name=\"budgetAmount\"/></td>"+
    "<td></td>"+
    "</tr>");

    $(".btnSave").bind("click", Save);     
    $(".btnDelete").bind("click", Delete);
};
$(function(){
//Add, Save, Edit and Delete functions code
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", Add);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up jsp and javascript.
Jsp executes on the server generating html and javascript.

```
"<select>"
+
<c:forEach var="budget" items="${budgetName}">
                "<option>${budget.budgetName}</option>"
</c:forEach>
+
"</select>"
```

The  executes on the server creating several option tags and the final output is streamed to the browser.

Comment: That didn't work, however I did find that if I used single quotes instead of double quotes with the escape character it worked correctly.